# MySQL LOOP with a procedure and function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, loops

I have a PROCEDURE, which SELECT some DATA by a WHERE-clause.
The DATA_A contains only one column.

A FUNCTION is created to convert an input to a different output.

Now i want this:

For each value in DATA_A convert the value using the FUNCTION.

Than everything should be returned.

How i could do this?

Thanks for any hint...

Comment: `select function(data_a) from yourtable`.

Comment: I don't understand this, because what is yourtable?

TABLE_A contains some colums, where i pick just one with a specific WHERE-clause by a PROCEDURE.

The FUNCTION is coded to input just 1 value per call. So how i call the FUNCTION with all these values i had?

I'm new to this kind of programming and i want this directly done by sql not php or so...

Comment: When you call this select statement it'll perform your function on each result returned from the table. I'm assuming yourtable translates into DATA_A